# Quotient Noetherian module

Tags: modules

Let $M$ be a module over the commutative ring $R$  and suppose that $N$ and $H$ are submodules of $M$ such that $M/N$ and $M/H$ are both Noetherian.

Show that $M/(N \cap H)$  is Noetherian.

I took any arbitrary submodules $K/(N \cap H)$, I must show this is finitely generated. From here $K$ is a submodule of $M$. From here how can I say $K/(N\cap H)$ is finitely generated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an injective module homomorphism from $M/(N\cap H)$ to $(M/N)\oplus(M/H)$
so $M/(N\cap H)$ is isomorphic to a submodule of $(M/N)\oplus(M/H)$.
Each submodule of a Noetherian module is Noetherian, and $(M/N)\oplus(M/H)$
is Noetherian.